# Corona SDK - problems getting scaled images to work

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lua, coronasdk

Reading the docs it says that different image sizes will kick in when `display.pixelWidth / display.actualContentWidth` is greater than or equal to the value of the value assigned to your image suffix.  No matter what I'm doing `display.actualContentWidth`is printing out 0.. making the value infinity..  I've tried all kinds of diff projects and diff config.lua files but I'm having the same problem no matter what.  Any ideas??

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- config.lua
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print(display.pixelWidth)
print(display.actualContentWidth)
print( display.pixelWidth / display.actualContentWidth )

application = {
    content = {
        width = 768,
        height = 1024,
        scale = "letterbox",
        fps = 60,
        imageSuffix = {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the statements in `main.lua` (or any other Lua file that you call that is not `config.lua`). You're trying to print the values before the have been initialized in Corona.

When it comes to scale images this one have worked very well for me: https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/